# audio tag play sound from another site

Tags: javascript, file, audio, playback

I want to play a sound file from another server With javascript from another server But it does not work for me. Why?

```
var audioPlayerPlayAll = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
audioPlayerPlayAll.src = 'www.vcollege.co.il/snd/link.mp3';
audioPlayerPlayAll.play();
```

The sound file is very short, about 2 seconds But still he can not play it.

Answer (score 1):

The direction you're using does not contain http or https protocol.

```
var audioPlayerPlayAll = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
audioPlayerPlayAll.src = '**http://**www.vcollege.co.il/snd/link.mp3';
audioPlayerPlayAll.play();
```

With www you are referring to a file called www.vcollege.co.il. 
That is to say, you want a mp3 at: http://***/www.vcollege.co.il/snd/link.mp3 
Protocols should always be included when you make calls from other domains. 
(In the address bar of browsers that are being left to use because they filled this automatically. The www, and the protocol is automatically detected, but programming does not work well.) 
Sorry my english use google translator.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities. The first is that the audio element has not loaded the sound by the time you want to play it. When you set the `src` attribute, it makes an asynchronous call to download the audio file and if it hasn't downloaded by the time you want to play it, nothing happens.

The second possibility is that the src isn't www.vcollege.co.il/and/link.mp3 but http://vcollege.co.il/snd/link.mp3.

Comment: Try using an Audio javascript element (audioPlayerPlayAll = new Audio();) instead of an Audio DOM element